# Hyper-V virtual Ethernet switch constantly appears and dissapears

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, network-adapter

I need Hyper-V, but when I turn it on, Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter (vEthernet Default Switch) constantly appears with Identification status and then disappears. This causes trouble, for example, frequent reconnections while using the Internet.

I can't delete the adapter, I tried to remove it from the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vmsmp\parameters\SwitchList`) and delete device from device manager, but it didn't help. I also tried to remove and add Hyper-V components, no result.

I have Windows 10, 64 bit, and Intel ethernet connection i219-v.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I found to this, was to open the Hyper V manager and stop the service altogether. Or via Services app. I started getting this problem when I took away my router and connected directly to ISP gateway. The default switch is making my ethernet adapter reset every 40 seconds! It’s very frustrating. I don’t exactly know the cause, it might have to do with domain and DNS (since I’m getting those from my ISP).